# No such file or directory when copying files to current directory

Tags: directory, filenames

I am trying to copy a file from inside a bunch of folders to the current directory I am in.
Playing around with the terminal, I see that when I specify the entire location it works:

```
joostin@ubuntu:~$ cp ~/unixstuff/vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt .
```

But when I go into the unixstuff folder and try to bring it into the current directly I get an error. Any idea what is going on?

```
joostin@ubuntu:~$ cd unixstuff
joostin@ubuntu:~/unixstuff$ cp /vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt .
cp: cannot stat ‘/vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such directory /vol, but it is vol (without slash), so try just

```
 cp vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt .
```

Answer (score 0):

`/vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt` is an absolute path. When a path begins with `/` (slash), it starts from the root directory. If you want the path to start at the current directory (relative path), it must not start with a slash.

```
joostin@ubuntu:~$ cd unixstuff
joostin@ubuntu:~/unixstuff$ cp vol/examples/tutorial/science.txt .
```